# VSE using two Effect Stips

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to add some images onto a video. Each of those images has transform key-frames to make them look less static. And each image blends with the others for smoother transitions. 
[image: VSE Effect layers]

I tried to find something, and I think I am supposed to use "Meta strips", but I never used them and they seem very complicated. Isn't there an easy way to do this? I guess I could render each image with key-frames, and add them in video form back in, but that wouldn't simplify a thing!

Sadly I only found out that it was an issue after rendering -.-

I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: Blend the transform strips into each other instead of the original ones as you do right now. Just remove the blend effects and add them again onto the green strips. =)

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't write solved as part of the title for the question. Accept the answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Blend the transform strips into each other instead of the original ones as you do right now.

Just remove the blend effects and add them again onto the green strips.